# How to link CSS with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm beginning to do HTML, CSS and PHP and I can't have a clear cut answer on how to add CSS to my existing PHP file:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_conjugate.php" media="screen" /> 
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $arr verbs = [
            verbs
        ];

        $arr base verbs= [
            base verbs
        ];



        for ($i = 0; $i < $max.baseverbs; $i++)
        {
            foreach (verbs as pronoun => conjugation) 
            {
                echo
            }
            echo for linebreak
        }   

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the verbs to be displayed in blue, which needs tobe done in PHP, according to what I have read, however I can't get it to work.

I can't seem to specify how the colour should be changed in the php script`:

```
php.conjugation
{
  blue color
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your exact question? Why not style the outputted HTML like usual HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying your CSS file to be a "text/css", however you are linking to a `.php` file.

You need to firstly create a new stylesheet (CSS File) with the `.css` extension.
Create a file called `style.css` in your directory and link it into your PHP file with the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

The contents of your stylesheet should contain the following class which you can use to get blue text:

**style.css:**

```css
.text-blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Now you can use this CSS class in your PHP `echo` to apply the color blue on the `$conjugation` variable:

```php
foreach ($arr_pronoun_to_conjugation as $pronoun => $conjugation) 
{
    echo "$pronoun " . $arr_verbstem[$i] . " <div class='text-blue'>$conjugation</div><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have missed to include below line into your style.php file.

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```